# Connecting to an SMTP server

Tags: node.js, smtp

Can anyone please guide me on how I can make a connection to SMTP server without use of any libraries, my googling efforts have only led me nodemailer and the likes but i would realy like a snippet which makes direct connection to smtp server. Thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to follow this approach you will have to write SMTP Protocol from the scratch, which will be very advanced and time consuming. Maybe 100+ hours. Look at the source code of nodemailer

Comment: okay good to know, thanks